# Mysql Mariadb user not able to access DB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I created a schema and granted its permission to a specific user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON USED_CARS.* TO ANDREW@LOCALHOST;
```

The database is created with root user and then granted these permissions to another user. now when I swith to another account I can list the schema with `SHOW SCHEMAS;` query however cannot switch to that DB with `use USED_CARS;` query.

Following error pops up:

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'ANDREW'@'localhost' to database 'USED_CARS'

What am I missing here? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `USED_CARS` is a database? You must indicate tables, with wildcard for all tables: `db_name.*`. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/#syntax

Comment: Yes USED_CARS is a database, and I tried with the wild card, still access is denied.

Comment: Another point is localhost must be in lowercase. Check your error message, access denied for `'ANDREW'@'localhost'`.
If your database and user names are in uppercase, the correct syntax should be: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON USED_CARS.* TO 'ANDREW'@'localhost';`

Comment: tried it, did not work as well..

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes depending on the configuration of server, you can use localhost or the ip:127.0.0.1

Could you try with this ...

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON USED_CARS.* TO 'ANDREW'@'%';

Comment: it responds with >can't find a matching role in user table.

Comment: if you try with: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON USED_CARS.* TO 'ANDREW'@'LOCALHOST';

Comment: same issue, access denied.